# Save profile photo to a storage folder in Laravel with Tenancy for Laravel package

Tags: php, laravel, inertiajs, laravel-jetstream

I developed a multi-tenant app using Tenancy for Laravel package with Jetstream Inertia stack. It worked okay on both landlord and tenant domain but when I tried to update a user's profile photo on a tenant subdomain (shop.localhost:8000), the uploaded photo was put outside the storage directory- check this picture below.
[image]

How can I save any files to the storage directory instead? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you please share the code samples how you store your files

Comment: Laravel Jetstream offers these features including login, registration, email verification, two-factor authentication, session management and the rest by default so I did not configure or make any changes to them. When I updated the photo on central site, it worked fine instead of the subdomain.

Answer (score 0):

Without more information, it is hard to pinpoint the cause of the problem you are facing. Maybe Tenancy's older documentation about "[Filesystem Tenancy](https://tenancyforlaravel.com/docs/v1/filesystem-tenancy/)" is a good place to start.

**NOTE**: the link is to their older version documentation. (The same topic is not as easily found in V3's docs.)
As per their words:

> Note: It's important to differentiate between storage_path() and the Storage facade. The Storage facade is what you use to put files into storage, i.e. Storage::disk('local')->put(). storage_path() is used to get the path to the storage directory.

I used the following search string:

> laravel tenancy how to save tenant images in their folders

to get the reference, seeing that documentation is not always up to date for most projects.
They cover a fairly extensive discussion of how to apply storage path configurations with `config('tenancy.filesystem.suffix_base') . $uuid`.